# Probably very simple- getting three containers adjacent to each other?

Tags: html, containers

I have three div containers, all the same size, and I used margin-left to shift the latter two to be, vertically, in their own spaces and separate from the first (left-most) container.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw6bQ.png

The bad news is, each is going on to their own line... If I had only two containers, I know I could float:left one and float:right the other, problem solved... but what about three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you add this to the css of all the divs:

```
display:inline-block;
```

note: you may need to remove the float values for this to work!

Edit:

If your div's are leaving unexplained gaps between each other, try remove the white space between each of them, like so:

```
<div>
    My Content
</div><div>
    My Content
</div><div>
    My Content
</div>
```

Comment: How is that better/worse than using float:left as suggested by SLaks?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I feel like float could give you undesired results in the future, like centering all the divs in the middle of the page. Also, float tends to mess around with the height of div, which effects the divs below them.

Comment: Replacing float:left with display:inline-block leaves the rightmost container with a gap between the other two (or if I remove the rightmost container, the new "right container" has a gap adjacent to the left container). Any ideas on this?

Comment: If you haven't set your margin 0px, do that and see if it fixes it. If you've already done that, it's probably because you've left white space between closing your div, and opening a new one. For example **<div>Your Content</div> <div>** and **<div>Your Content</div><div>** show different results. HTML is weird like that! I'll add an example into my post for you.

Comment: Gotcha, I thought that space only mattered within tags... At any rate, I was messing around with the styling, adding webkit shadows to one of them, then removed all that to try your suggestion... without changing anything with relation to spacing (your suggestion), they're now all equidistant, looks like four pixels... I mean, as long as they're all equidistant, I don't mind the small padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `float: left` all three of them.
You only need a `margin` if you want a gap between the boxes.

Comment: One empty div with `clear: left` at the bottom also?